# The easiest way to automatically open a popup?

Tags: html, css, popup

I wish to automatically open a popup when users enter my website.
What is the easiest way to do this?

- The popup should be in a `div`
- A close button should appear in order to close the popup

I've tried a couple of solutions with jquery and CSS but sometimes the close button didn't close the popup and with other solutions sometimes the script just didn't work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try [jQuery Dialog] (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally use a jQuery UI dialog, but if you want something simpler, here you go:

If this is your html div:

```
<div id="popup">
    <h1>Welcome</h1> 
    <span id="closePopup">Close</span>
</div>
```

And this is your CSS (positioning of pop up may not be perfect, this is rough):

```
#popup{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    width:50%;
    left:25%;
}
#popupClose{
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Then this is your javascript(jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popup').show(); //show the pop up on page load
    $('#popupClose').click(function(){  //when the user clicks on the word close
        $('#popup').close();  //close the pop up
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="popup"><span class="close">close</span>..</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup{ 
  display: none;
  ...
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.popup').show();

   $(".close").click(function(){
   $(".popup").hide();
   });
})
```